# Meaning of being a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

A Cauchy sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$ is a sequence for which the distance between two terms can be made as small as we want, provided we look far enough in the sequence.

Let $X \subseteq Y$, where $Y$ is a set on which $d$ can be extended. Is it always true that for any Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ one can find $y\in Y$ such that $d(x_n,y)\rightarrow 0$?

In other words, is it true that every Cauchy sequence "converges" to something? (and  if this something is in $X$ we say it is convergent?)

Comment: No. In fact, the property you are describing is called completeness. A metric space is $complete$ if every Cauchy sequence converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the concept of the **completion** of the metric space $X$.

Here you construct $Y$ by adding to $X$ an "artificial" limit element for each Cauchy sequence that doesn't already have one in $X$ -- or rather, for each *equivalence class* of such Cauchy sequence where sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are related if $d(x_n,y_n)\to 0$.

One main example of this is that $\mathbb R$ is a metric completion of $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: So my question could be rephrased into: does every metric space admit a completion?

Comment: @Leonardo: Yes it does. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space#Completion) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

No, in order to show that a Cauchy Sequence converges, a more delicate approach would be needed and that's not always the case. If, though, one proves that for a space $(X,d) \subseteq (Y,d)$ it is $d(x_n,y) \to 0$ for a Cauchy Sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N} \in X$, that means that the space $X$ equipped with the metric $d$ is complete, thus Banach (if the metric $d$ is a norm of course, thus we are dealing with a complete normed space).

Comment: Banach is terminology for complete normed spaces.

Comment: I didn't specify $y \in X$. So what you're saying is that is if $\exists y \in Y $ such that $ d(x_n,y) $ vanishes then I could prove $y \in X$?

Comment: @Leonardo I didn't say $y \in X$.

Comment: @Rebellos But a complete metric space $(X,d)$ is one in which every Cauchy sequence in $X$ is convergent in X, so when you said that $(X,d)$ is complete if $d(x_n,y)$ vanishes you're implying $ y \in X$, aren't you?